# Struggling to understand Android Fragments and device rotations

Tags: android, android-fragments

I built a very simple Android app with a button for adding `Fragments` and a `LinearLayout` for hosting fragments. When the device rotates, the Fragments are reinstated in the correct layout. It works.

However, if I copy the code of the simple app described above in an `Activity` with a more complex user interface, `Fragments` disappears when the device rotates. From the log messages I cannot understand why.

This is the layout containing the `LinearLayout` for the fragments.

[image: Layout]

This is the longest question I have ever written, I hope someone will have enough patience to read till the end.

The `Activity` has these two fields that I use for attaching instances of `Fragment`:

```
protected static String FRAGMENT_TAG = "tag_";
protected int fragmentIndex = 10000;
```

New fragments are created when the user taps on a `Button` with this listener:

```
addPacketIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addPacketIV);
        addPacketIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addNewPacketFragment();
            }
});

protected void addNewPacketFragment() {
        Log.d(TAG, "");
        int currentFragmentIndex= fragmentIndex++;
        String tagForFragment = FRAGMENT_TAG + currentFragmentIndex;
        Log.d(TAG, "\n** Creating new Packet Editor TAG= " + tagForFragment);
        addPacketEditor(tagForFragment);
}

protected void addPacketEditor(String fragmentTag) {
   if(fragmentTag == null) {
     Log.d(TAG, "Received a null fragmentTag - should never happen!");
     return;
   }

   PacketEditorFragment fragment = (PacketEditorFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);

   if(fragment == null) {
       Log.d(TAG, "No fragment found for tag " + fragmentTag + " - create new one");
       fragment = PacketEditorFragment.newInstance();
       fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
       getSupportFragmentManager()
               .beginTransaction()
               .add(R.id.packetsFragmentContainer, fragment, fragmentTag)
               .commit();
            Log.d(TAG, "New fragment created and added to linear layout: " + fragmentTag);
   } else {
       Log.d(TAG, "Fragment " + fragmentTag + " already attached to this activity");
   }

   Log.d(TAG, "Adding this fragment to allFragments: " + fragment.getTag());
   allFragments.add(fragment);

   Log.d(TAG, "Printing fragments:");
   int nFrags = allFragments.size();
   for(int i=0; i<nFrags; i++) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Fragment " + i + " - tag " + allFragments.get(i).getTag());
   }

   Log.d(TAG, "Num of attached fragment allFragments.size(): " + allFragments.size());
   Log.d(TAG, "Num of attached fragment packetContainer.childCount(): " + packetFragmentContainerVG.getChildCount());
} // addPacketEditor
```

When a fragment is added I print the number of fragments stored in the `List allFragments` and check how many fragments are attached to their container `R.id.packetFragmentContainerVG`.

When the device rotates, I store the fragment tags in the state `Bundle`:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState called");
    Log.d(TAG, "packetContainer.childCount() " + packetFragmentContainerVG.getChildCount());

    // Store the index for future fragments
    outState.putInt(KEY_STATE_FRAGMENT_INDEX, fragmentIndex);
    Log.d(TAG, "Saved current fragment index: " + fragmentIndex);

    int nPackets = allFragments.size();


    // Store the number of packet fragments
    outState.putInt(KEY_STATE_N_PACKET_EDITORS, nPackets);
    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: " +  nPackets + " packets");

    // for each attached fragment store its tag
    for(int i=0; i<nPackets; i++) {
        String fragmentTag = allFragments.get(i).getTag();
        Log.d(TAG, "Saving fragment " + i +") " + fragmentTag);
        outState.putString(KEY_STATE_PACKET_FRAGMENT + i, fragmentTag);
    } // for
} // onSaveInstanceState
```

And this is the `onRestoreInstanceState(.)`:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
    fragmentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_STATE_FRAGMENT_INDEX);
    Log.d(TAG, "Restored index for fragments: " + fragmentIndex);
    restorePacketEditors(savedInstanceState);
}

protected void restorePacketEditors(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int nSavedPackets = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_STATE_N_PACKET_EDITORS);
    Log.d(TAG, "Restoring packets, number: " + nSavedPackets);
    for(int i = 0; i<nSavedPackets; i++) {
        String fragmentTag = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_STATE_PACKET_FRAGMENT+i);
        Log.d(TAG, i+") has tag " + fragmentTag);
        addPacketEditor(fragmentTag);
    }
} // restorePacketEditors
```

These are the log messages of a typical interaction. This is the first screenshot: fragments are added by tapping on the `+` image view.

[image: Start]

**The first fragment is created with tag `tag_10000`**

```
No fragment found for tag tag_10000 - create new one
New fragment created and added to linear layout: tag_10000
Adding this fragment to allFragments: tag_10000
Printing fragments:
Fragment 0 - tag tag_10000
Num of attached fragment allFragments.size(): 1
Num of attached fragment packetContainer.childCount(): 0
```

**These are the log messages printed when other two fragments are added:**

```
No fragment found for tag tag_10001 - create new one
New fragment created and added to linear layout: tag_10001
Adding this fragment to allFragments: tag_10001
Printing fragments:
Fragment 0 - tag tag_10000
Fragment 1 - tag tag_10001
Num of attached fragment allFragments.size(): 2
Num of attached fragment packetContainer.childCount(): 1
No fragment found for tag tag_10002 - create new one
New fragment created and added to linear layout: tag_10002
Adding this fragment to allFragments: tag_10002
Printing fragments:
Fragment 0 - tag tag_10000
Fragment 1 - tag tag_10001
Fragment 2 - tag tag_10002
Num of attached fragment allFragments.size(): 3
Num of attached fragment packetContainer.childCount(): 2
```

Three fragments are added: you can recognize them from the red background color.

[image: Three fragments added]

**At this point the device rotates, onSaveInstanceState is called**

```
onSaveInstanceState called
packetContainer.childCount() 3
Saved current fragment index: 10003
onSaveInstanceState: 3 packets
Saving fragment 0) tag_10000
Saving fragment 1) tag_10001
Saving fragment 2) tag_10002
OnStop called
```

**... onRestoreInstanceState is called**

```
onRestoreInstanceState
Restored index for fragments: 10003
Restoring packets, there are: 3
0) has tag tag_10000
Fragment tag_10000 already attached to this activity
Adding this fragment to allFragments: tag_10000
Printing fragments:
Fragment 0 - tag tag_10000
Num of attached fragment allFragments.size(): 1
Num of attached fragment packetContainer.childCount(): 3
1) has tag tag_10001
Fragment tag_10001 already attached to this activity
Adding this fragment to allFragments: tag_10001
Printing fragments:
Fragment 0 - tag tag_10000
Fragment 1 - tag tag_10001
Num of attached fragment allFragments.size(): 2
Num of attached fragment packetContainer.childCount(): 3
2) has tag tag_10002
Fragment tag_10002 already attached to this activity
Adding this fragment to allFragments: tag_10002
Printing fragments:
Fragment 0 - tag tag_10000
Fragment 1 - tag tag_10001
Fragment 2 - tag tag_10002
Num of attached fragment allFragments.size(): 3
Num of attached fragment packetContainer.childCount(): 3
There are 3 fragments
0) tag_10000
1) tag_10001
2) tag_10002
```

**Even if everything looks ok, only two out of the three `Fragment`s are shown, specifically only the second one.**

[image: First rotation, only one packet]

**Indeed, there's something wrong as you can see when the device rotates again**

```
onSaveInstanceState called
Saved current fragment index: 10003
onSaveInstanceState: 3 packets
Saving fragment 0) null
Saving fragment 1) tag_10001
Saving fragment 2) null
OnStop called
```

**As you can see, two out of the three `Fragments` now have a `null` tag. Between the two rotations nothing happened: there was no user interaction at all**

If the device rotates again, no fragments are shown.

[image: After two rotations, no fragments]

If you are still reading, then be aware that you will have a free pizza&beer when you visit Italy.

If you are able to solve this problem, then I will include also a dinner in one of the best local restaurant - but you have to come to Italy first.

PS. Forgive the typos introduced by auto-completion with language set to Italian. I could correct them, but they are not relevant for the problem discussed in this question.

Comment: @bwegs Since you are coming, may be it's worth providing an answer :-)

Comment: Can we see some pictures to get a visual of what's going on?

Comment: @bwegs Ok, I will prepare the screenshots.

Comment: @bwegs I added the screenshots.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about this to tell you what the problem is but if you haven't already looked through the Android dev docs then this may be useful - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html